# React Native android release error A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'. > Could not find method splits() for arguments error

Tags: java, android, reactjs, react-native, gradle

i have a problem when receiving application release
`yarn android --variant release` i'm running this command and gives me the following error;

```
yarn android --variant release
yarn run v1.22.19
$ react-native run-android --variant release
info Starting JS server...
info Launching emulator...
info Successfully launched emulator.
info Installing the app...
5 actionable tasks: 5 up-to-date
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                                                                                                                                                                         

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\user_0\Desktop\AwesomeProject\android\app\build.gradle' line: 216

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method splits() for arguments [build_9cj0nm0uy7u5p9mmnrxyr8ysi$_run_closure6@3c34a482] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 3s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installRelease -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\user_0\Desktop\AwesomeProject\android\app\build.gradle' line: 216

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method splits() for arguments [build_9cj0nm0uy7u5p9mmnrxyr8ysi$_run_closure6@3c34a482] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 3s

    at makeError (C:\Users\user_0\Desktop\AwesomeProject\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at C:\Users\user_0\Desktop\AwesomeProject\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\user_0\Desktop\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\user_0\Desktop\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:142:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android i followed these steps exactly. i tried again 3-4 times but nothing changes. how can i fix this ?